# Combine several arrays into an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, accumulator

Say I have three arrays depicting some names, number of books read and how awesome these people [in names] are:

```
let names = ["Mary", "Joe", "Kenan"];
let numberOfBooks = [2, 1, 4];
let awesomenessLevel = ["pretty cool", "meh", "super-reader"];
```

I'm trying to use `.reduce()` to bring them together to create an array of objects containing the relevant index in each array, but I am failing miserably:

```
    let people = [
    {
       name: "Mary",
       noOfBooks: 2,
       awesomeness: "pretty cool"
    },
    {
       name: "Joe",
       noOfBooks: 1,
       awesomeness: "meh"
    },
    {
       name: "Kenan",
       noOfBooks: 4,
       awesomeness: "super-reader"
    }
  ]
```

I got it with reduce as well:

```
let arrFinal = [];

 names.reduce(function(all, item, index) {
  arrFinal.push({
    name: item,
    noOfBooks: numberOfBooks[index],
    awesomeness: awesomenessLevel[index]
  })
}, []);
```

Comment: The way you do it with `reduce`does not use the benefit of `reduce`: note how the callback does not return a value, and the *all* accumulator is not used, which are typical hallmarks of opting for `reduce`. You can just replace `reduce` with `forEach` in that code (and adjust the arguments -- without *all*), and it would not make a difference.

Comment: you're completely right, I just added them desperately :s. I guess I need to work more on how to use reduce properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it with `map`, like this:

```
let result = names.map( (v, i) => ({
    name: names[i], 
    noOfBooks: numberOfBooks[i],
    awesomenessLevel: awesomenessLevel[i]
}));
```

```js
let names = ["Mary", "Joe", "Kenan"];
let numberOfBooks = [2, 1, 4];
let awesomenessLevel = ["pretty cool", "meh", "super-reader"];

let result = names.map( (v, i) => ({
    name: names[i], 
    noOfBooks: numberOfBooks[i],
    awesomenessLevel: awesomenessLevel[i]
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

`map` works better than `reduce` in this case, because the number of elements you have in the *names* array (or any of the two others) is the same as the number of elements you need in the output. In that case it is more natural to use `map`.

Comment: you're right, I think with reduce there's the extra step of defining an array before whereas here you just load up the result. thanks very much for this

Comment: You're welcome ;-). See also some other thoughts about `reduce` in my comment to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Use `map` to create a 1-to-1 mapping between the input arrays and the output arrays.

```
let people = names.map(function (e, i) {
    return {name:e, noOfBooks:numberOfBooks[i],awesomeness: awesomenessLevel[i]};
});
```

```js
let names = ["Mary", "Joe", "Kenan"];
let numberOfBooks = [2, 1, 4];
let awesomenessLevel = ["pretty cool", "meh", "super-reader"];

let people = names.map(function (e, i) {
    return {name:e, noOfBooks:numberOfBooks[i],awesomeness: awesomenessLevel[i]};
});


console.log(people);
```

Comment: Just another useful info: instead of `alert` in a snippet, use `console.log`, and then you don't even need to do the `JSON.stringify` as StackOverflow does that for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dynamic approach by combining all arrays to one object and use the key names as property names for the result objects in the array

```js
let names = ["Mary", "Joe", "Kenan"],
    numberOfBooks = [2, 1, 4],
    awesomenessLevel = ["pretty cool", "meh", "super-reader"],
    object = { name: names, noOfBooks: numberOfBooks, awesomeness: awesomenessLevel },
    result = Object.keys(object).reduce((r, k) =>
        (object[k].forEach((a, i) =>
            (r[i] = r[i] || {})[k] = a), r), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```